# Fixed Sidebar for Navigation in Website

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, iframe

I want to have a sidebar in my website with navigation in it. I will use script like phpBB etc. but I want sidebar to be displayed on every page.

So I am thinking about making a Sidebar in HTML and then using frame tag for displaying other pages/scripts.

But as Frames are getting obsolute, Is there any other method to display a sidebar in everypage without using frames and without adding html coding on every page?

Answer (score 1):

Put your HTML in a PHP file (or HTML if you want) with no  or other tags aside from what you want to display, then put the following on each page you want to display the menu on:

```
<?php include ('page-name.php'); ?>
```

One line of code is all you need. If you make a change to the 'page-name.php' file, it updates on every page.

Cheers

Comment: Inserting it on a single php file wont work man...Cauz Like in phpBB, there are Files for Different Functions like Index.php for Index, ShowForum.php for Showing single forum... It Wont be displayed on every page unless I insert it on every file...

Comment: You could also have a line of jQuery in a common .js file that makes an `$.ajax` call to your sidebar content if you like that better.  You're probably already including the .js file, right?  Adding the include there keeps it out of your markup (which can be a good thing or a bad thing).

Comment: The problem is to Insert Include function in Every Script i.e If I use phpBB and eyeOS then I have to Insert that line to many places to include a js file...

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked here and on [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/7751/sidebar-for-navigation-in-website); I answered it over there.